# How to make ConfigurationManager use the assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class like

```
namespace LrcArchiveServices
{
    public static class SharedInfo
    {
        public static string ConnectionString { get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalDb"].ConnectionString; } }
    }
}
```

but the problem is that when I use `ShareInfo` in another assembly then I have to copy the values in the App/Web Config over to that assembly. How can I make this always grab the value in the assembly in which the class `SharedInfo` is contained?? Or is there a better way to share values between configs?

Comment: then , you can put hardcoded configuration in code!!!

Comment: You can create `SharedConfig.config`, make it `Copy when newer` and work with it. Every time you reference this assembly, `SharedConfig.config` will be copied to output directory. If you need to change this config, you will need to change it in one place (during design time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager` will always use the value from the **startup** assembly `app.config`.

If these are two separate applications which both have separate entry points, then they should have separate app.configs with a mirrored value in both configs. If this is a single application, where one of these assemblies depends on the other, then you only need to have the `app.config` defined in the assembly that is the entry point for your application.